# Adding Digital Signature to an XML Document for TLS

Tags: xml, ssl, public-key-encryption

In TLS, how do I add a digital signature to an XML document in C# or Java? Most importantly, at what point is the XML document encrypted? During the signature process or after?

Comment: What is TLS in your question?

Comment: Sorry. Transport Layer Security. I'm more interested in understanding what happens to the XML document after it is signed. Where does this signature go and at what point is the XML document encrypted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TLS is not related to the document signing in any way. TLS transfers any data and treats this data as a stream of bytes. Signing is done completely independently.

XML signature can be embedded into the document (i.e. signature-related XML nodes become a part of the document) or it can be stored in a separate file (detached signature). In both cases you can transfer the document over TLS or any other medium.